# How to update my data set?

Tags: c#, dataset

When i insert a data into my DB my data set (my *telerik grid view*) wont get updated I don't know how i should do that?

i'm in a 3 layer project my data set is in the first one but my inserting code is in the last one

here's my codes in first layer

```
 private void radButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Ref_View_Model = new View_model._View_Model();
        Ref_View_Model.GetAddCustomers(txtFName.Text, txtLName.Text, txtPhn.Text, txtDdrss.Text);

        txtFName.Clear();
        txtLName.Clear();
        txtPhn.Clear();
        txtDdrss.Clear();
        txtFName.Focus();
        MessageBox.Show("yore contact saved successfully", "Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
```

and here's my third layer

```
        public void AddCustomers(string _fName, string _lName, string _phone, string _address)
    {
        Connection_String = @"Data Source=MOSTAFA-PC;Initial Catalog=" + "Sales and Inventory System" + ";Integrated Security=TrueData Source=MOSTAFA-PC;Initial Catalog=" + "Sales and Inventory System" + ";Integrated Security=True;";
        Con = new SqlConnection();
        Con.ConnectionString = Connection_String;
        Con.Open();
        Cmd = new SqlCommand();
        Cmd.Connection = Con;
        Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        Cmd.CommandText = "insert into Customers(FName,LName,Phone,[Address])" +
                "values ('" + _fName + "','" + _lName + "','" + _phone + "','" + _address + "')";
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Cmd.Dispose();

    }
```

how can i update my data set??

Comment: Change SQL from 'insert' to 'update'.  See webpage https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx

Answer (score 0):

check this tuto 
www. youtube .com/watch?v=IcD9Jffstmw
remove space in link